# Tracking asset values via timestamp and querying without a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a persistent object that keeps track of the value of assets. I need to keep track of these values with timestamps so that I can run calculations of the assets current values against previous values.

Currently the object looks like this:

```
prices = {
    Tag1: { price: /*current price*/ },
    Tag2: { price: /*current price*/ }
}
```

And I have a function that runs every 5 minutes that updates that price:

```
function get_prices() {
  var tags = settings.tags, prices = settings.prices;
  for (var i in tags){
    prices[i]["current_price"] = ccvalue(i); //Gets value of asset and saves to current price.
  }
  //Save price object for persistence
  properties.setProperty('prices', JSON.stringify(prices));
}
```

Whenever the price is updated, I need to save it with a timestamp and push it in front of the old price. Then I need to have a way to run calculations against the price at different times, so I can know the difference from, for example, one hour or twenty-four hours ago.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while and I don't know how to use timestamps with this object in a way that I can quickly search for the timestamp closest to a certain time without looping through the object to check every single one.

Comment: Btw, may be its better idea to use a reactive framework for this kind of things? Like React.js, vue.js or angular-2? Solution to use a time dependent function just to track an object updates is terrible...

Comment: It's in Google Apps Script, I can't use any frameworks, only javascript. But there has to be a simple solution to this problem I'm not seeing, right?

Comment: `prices[i] = []` <- use an array, then you can simply `prices[i].unshift({price: ccvalue(i), date: +new Date})` to add a new entry